# Android. ListView row gets focus

Tags: android, listview

Whenever I wipe the data on the emulator and then run my app on it, the first row in the `ListView` always gets focus. By this i mean, it has the orange selection on it. Anyone have any idea on how I can get rid of it? I don't have any `EditTexts` or other `Views` in the `Activity` on which I can request focus instead.
I'm sure it's something trivial, but I can't seem to find the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like that:

```
ListView listView = (ListView)....;
listView.clearFocus();
```

Comment: yeah, like I said. Trivial. Now, the problem is that I can't figure out a placement for this method call so it will actually work. :( But anyway, I'll accept your answer, as it is the best one.

Comment: You should invoke this while your Activity/ListActivity is created, namely onCreate().

Comment: I placed it at the end of the `onCreate` method. Does not seem to work. Probably because I'm getting the `ListView` content from a remote location, and it does this in an asynchronous manner and it places the focus only after it receives the content and it populates the `ListView`. Well, I'll keep trying. At least now I know which method I need to use. :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `listview` xml

```
<ListView
.................

android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent" 
android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
/>
```

This will make the `listview` divider color to transparent. So it will not be seen as selected.

Comment: I think this's not the best solution because it directly effects the behaviour of the selector, which is most probably not wanted.

Comment: I'm guessing this will make it transparent every time I select an item from the list, which I don't want. I still want it to appear, just not at the first run of the app. faradaj, your solution is the one i'm looking for, I'm just having trouble with the placement of the method. At the end of the onCreate method does not work. I'm trying some other places and I'll tell 'ya how it works ;) Thanks.